# HTTP 503 : Service Unavailable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application, that perfectly works locally. Though, after uploading it to my host's server, the domain now returns "http 503" error ; I re-published the project from within vs many times but the problem persists.

One person in another question said it's a crash problem, though how since my app is working ?

After debugging, I got the output and here it is :

```
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Domain 2): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Caching\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Runtime.Caching.dll'. Symbols loaded.
A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0.dll'. Symbols loaded.
A first chance exception of type 'System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Security.SecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.JScript\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.JScript.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DynamicData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DynamicData.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\2982373d\e9af3651_2356d001\Antlr3.Runtime.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\432d1386\2fd0ecf8_9a71d001\BytsNBytes.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\1ef4f0eb\63b1025d_0f6fd001\EntityFramework.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\663b60c3\0860055d_0f6fd001\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\c4d82047\23cd0856_2356d001\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\2df2459a\77b73356_2356d001\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\39a24ccf\a7a42056_2356d001\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\395e37e1\cba15e56_2356d001\Microsoft.Owin.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\7256d552\a9db7856_2356d001\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\631df137\cdd8b656_2356d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\660764ab\2db39056_2356d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\04a05fba\5728a656_2356d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\0f1eb96d\53e72657_2356d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\02319735\f30c4d57_2356d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\bb7f228b\9debc956_2356d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\8308f0ae\7d5c3c57_2356d001\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure\v4.0_1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\59b1a30b\49d5dc50_2356d001\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\b89a07dd\ed674456_2356d001\Owin.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\74daad53\c1dae04f_2356d001\System.Web.Helpers.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\0be1ebdb\c93e4450_2356d001\System.Web.Mvc.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\a44139a0\bfa3884f_2356d001\System.Web.Optimization.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\d406d2b5\e0c53f4f_2356d001\System.Web.Razor.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\d31b065d\759fe54f_2356d001\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\7c9c6215\2964ea4f_2356d001\System.Web.WebPages.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\46c5e003\83c6ec4f_2356d001\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\assembly\dl3\be087d70\89d55c51_2356d001\WebGrease.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader\v4.0_1.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Loader.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment\v4.0_2.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xaml.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime\v4.0_2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Tracing\v4.0_2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Tracing.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.RegularExpressions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.RegularExpressions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Services.Design\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Services.Design.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\App_global.asax.qiwhtxw_.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Internals\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Workflow.ComponentModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Workflow.ComponentModel.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Workflow.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Workflow.Activities.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Workflow.Runtime\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Workflow.Runtime.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Linq.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.SqlXml.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xaml.Hosting\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Xaml.Hosting.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Net.Http\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Net.Http.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.DurableInstancing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Security\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Security.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.DataVisualization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.DataVisualization.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Build.Framework\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll'. Symbols loaded.
A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Dynamic\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Dynamic.dll'. Symbols loaded.
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in BytsNBytes.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll'. Symbols loaded.
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-EntityFramework'. 
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-BytsNBytes'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\App_Web_n2bonnra.dll'. 
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\App_Web_erouy4nj.dll'. 
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Users\User0\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6ae02a6d\6ab4d59c\App_Web_2ktmhc3s.dll'. 
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in Microsoft.CSharp.dll
'iisexpress.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/9/ROOT-1-130729680602128906): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.HtmlParser\v4.0_2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.HtmlParser.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
```

is it a problem from the host's company ? note the exception :cannot find or open pdb file..these are system dlls !

Please tell me how such an error can originate, while the app actually works ?

Hence, an older version also worked perfectly before (even on the host's machine), yet now after publishing the older version, it doesn't work.

Comment: Check the App pool in IIS , make sure it is not set to Integrated Mode.. Also check which .Net Framework it is pointing to.

Comment: looks like server issue, cant be use iisexpress.exe on a server !

Comment: @KD it always points to .net 4.5 , also iis express is locally installed ; I don't know how to access that on the server.. locally I have no problems at all

Comment: @aristos hmmm my guess also, I spent a whole day tracing this and nothing online pointed out but to crash issues, which were eliminated after the code ran successfully. I will to contact the technical support of the host's company.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair , seems legit : ) Edited

Comment: You have lots of security and entity exception issues.  It is very strange that this would be running on IISExpress on a hosted server.  IISExpress is not suitable for a production application.  Also, it looks like you are having issues connecting to your database.  I agree that discussing these issues with the host tech support is the way to go.

Comment: @SteveMitcham Thank you for the reply ; yes the technical support provided the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try running  "aspnet_regiis.exe"
( Open command prompt in administrator mode and go to 
      C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 (if its a 32 bit pc)
      C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319 (if it is a 64 bit pc)
then type  aspnet_regiis.exe -i and press enter)

Answer (score 0):

The technical support of the host's company just replied. They fixed the site via restarting the app pool.

The reason was that the mvc project (when running) is consuming too much memory (i.e which is true since I have portions of code which process thousands of instances).

When that happens and the consumption exceeds the site's memory, the project is recycled automatically by IIS ; thus the problem occurs, and the application pool must be restarted in order for the site to work again.

Please, add this to your list of reasons, why "http 503" might occur. It might -as in my case- root back to the hosting plan & the site's memory.

https://besthostingforasp.net/asp-net-service-unavailable-503-error-using-shared-windows-server/

Comment: @MarkSpencer indeed ; I need more exercise around handling large amounts of data. Probably I published a faulty version at some point that caused IIS to die.. Thankfully the current published version is going well, but I need to keep optimizing.